# Creating table in database using hibernate auto-ddl is not creating the table as required

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a application in spring boot and using hibernate for persistance. I have set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. But the created table in the database is not correct. These are my 3 entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tContent")
public class Content extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Content_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String Description;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tContentTag", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Content_ID", referencedColumnName = "Content_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="Tag_ID", referencedColumnName = "Tag_ID")
            )
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    public Content() {
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="tTag")
public class Tag extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Tag_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Tag_Name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci")
    private String tagName ;

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName ;
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName;
    }


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tContentTag")
public class ContentTag implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Content_ID", unique = false)
    private Content content;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Tag_ID", unique=false)
    private Tag tag;
}
```

And this is how table is created in the database

```
CREATE TABLE `t_content` (
  `content_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE `t_tag` (
  `tag_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tag_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE `t_content_tag` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `content_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`,`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_33lrnpl9s4uomdag4n2iftghp` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKggjqilc3bfp75f3bqne5qlill` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `t_tag` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKjwge9erpywu6jvn5thsixrabt` FOREIGN KEY (`content_id`) REFERENCES `t_content` (`content_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Column Content_ID in t_Content_Tag table is not auto increment, and id in the same table is auto increment but it is not created as auto increment coulmn. How to create these tables properly. t_Content_Tag table is a linking table.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Update cannot correct table if constraints have already been defined. You can use create-drop until you get the definition right.

Comment: I am using create-drop now. I am not getting any error, but the created table is not correct. table t_content_tag should have id, content_id, tag_id and content_id is not a auto increatent as it is refering to to t_content table.

Comment: Why do you need tContentTag? Why not keep a simple one to many relation between content and tag.

Comment: If if do like that, how the table will be ? And i tTag is a master table and will be referred by so many other tables also